# directadmin nginx ip conf

Tags: nginx

Где находится файл настройки нжинкс, который открывает страницу с надписью

> "Nginx is functioning normally"

Comment: начните с `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`. если не увидите иного в списке процессов: `$ pgrep -a nginx`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

во-первых, определите, не вызывается ли программа *nginx* с указанием какого-нибудь конфигурационного файла, задаваемого опцией `-c /путь/к/конф/файлу`. это можно увидеть в списке процессов:

```
$ pgrep -a nginx
```

если подобной опции в выводе данной команды не наблюдается, то, скорее всего, это файл `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.

во-вторых, просмотрите данный файл на предмет секций `server {...}`. если обнаружите — вероятно, какая-то из них и определяет искомую вами конфигурацию.

если таких секций не обнаружите, поищите директиву подключения конф.файлов `include /путь/к/конф/файлу`, и просмотрите уже эти файлы на предмет секций `server {...}`.

p.s. частенько можно встретить такую, например, директиву:

```
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*
```

означает она «подключение всех файлов в каталоге `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`.