# У меня Nginx или Apache?

Tags: apache, nginx, хостинг

Ответ от сервера сайта(виртуальный хостинг):

```
Server: nginx/1.8.0
Date: Sat, 02 Sep 2017 17:54:44 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.28
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: User-Agent
```

Судя по всему, сайт на nginx. Но почему у него в директории есть файл .htacces?

При подключении к SSH ввожу:

```
# whereis apache
apache: /usr/local/apache

# whereis nginx
nginx: /usr/lib64/nginx
```

Как это понимать? Конфигурационного файла Nginx я не нахожу. В cpanel управлении хостинга есть подменю "Обработчики Apache"

Какой у меня сервер, Nginx или Apache?

Comment: Скорее всего - оба, обрабатывают цепочкой

Comment: Apache за Nginx.

Comment: *Конфигурационного файла Nginx я не нахожу* https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/651610/178576

Comment: Раз в заголовке написано server: nginx, то 146% за то, что на фронте стоит nginx. Есть Apache за ним или нет - второй вопрос. Наличие файлов. htacces в папках ни о чем не говорит - они могли остаться с предыдущего сервера. nginx их просто игнорирует. То, что вы не можете найти файл nginx, не значит, что его нет. Абсолютно точно - он есть, раз в ответе сервера написано nginx. Когда найдёте файл конфигурации nginx, в нем и увидите, работает ли он сам по себе или отдаёт запросы в Apache.